# different number of command line arguments

Tags: java, sockets, command-line-arguments

the following code gives
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    url cannot be resolved to a variable"
error. There can be three or four command line arguments, so I used an if statement to test it, but the code doesn't seem to get String url from the command line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    Socket sock = new Socket("kjlkjlkjl", 80);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
    writer.write("GET "+ url +"HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            + "Host: jhkjhkjhkjh\r\n"
            + "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
            + "\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Usually checking array length `args.length` is what you need when you are handling variable number of arguments

Answer (score 3):

You determine you `url` inside `if-else` statment and it's not visible for your `writer`.

Change your code in next way:

```
    String url;
    String target;
    String replacement;
    int odd = -1;
    if(args.length > 3)
    {
        odd = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        url = args[1];
        target = args[2];
        replacement = args[3];
    }
    else if(args.length > 2)
    {
        url = args[0];
        target = args[1];
        replacement = args[2];
    }
```

EDIT: I think you need to watch [basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/)

Comment: now it throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 exception

Comment: Edit your if statment. you must to validate count of arguments

Comment: I also had to initiliaze strings, too by making them equal to ""

Answer (score 1):

To add on to what @alex2410 said, this is a scoping issue. All declared variables have a specific scope they can be recognized in. A variable's scope can be determined by the nearest set of enclosing curly braces. Your example above has two declarations of 'url' inside an if/else if block. This means their scope is limited to that block. @alex2410 proposed a correct solution which gives the String url a scope limited to the main method.